# Concatenating columns to DataFrame using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Dataframe contains

```
TRANSACTION FILE
 AS REPORT 2018-12-02
 Jeff Thomoson   000 11-28-2018 Payments  2,400    Wired transfer
 Jeff Thomoson   000 11-29-2018 Interest    100    account
 Paul Simson     000 11-12-2018 Payments  1,000  Wired transfer
 Paul Simson     000 11-18-2018 Payments    100    net banking
 John Sans       000 11-28-2018 Payments    300    cheque
                                Total   3,900
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
bad_words = ['TRANSACTION','REPORT','Total']
with open('e:\\data\\test.txt') as oldfile, open('e:\\data\\processed.txt', 'w') as newfile:
for line in oldfile:
    if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
        newfile.write(line)

df_a = pd.read_csv('e:\\data\\processed.txt',header=None)
names = ['USER','NAME', 'TR Mode', 'Date', 'Narration', 'Amt', 'Mode']
df=pd.read_fwf('e:\\data\\processed.txt', header=None, names=names,dtype=str)
```

I was trying to concatenate the values from the variable (LedgerCode). but its adding all the columns as '02'

```
LedgerCode='02'
```

tried f-string expression, but no luck.

```
f"{LedgerCode}"+ df[['USER','NAME', 'TR Mode', 'Date', 'Narration', 'Amt', 'Mode']]
```

Expected results would like:

```
02 Jeff Thomoson   000 11-28-2018 Payments  2,400    Wired transfer
02 Jeff Thomoson   000 11-29-2018 Interest    100    account
02 Paul Simson     000 11-12-2018 Payments  1,000    Wired transfer
02 Paul Simson     000 11-18-2018 Payments    100    net banking
02 John Sans       000 11-28-2018 Payments    300    cheque
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you stick to f-string expression.

```
df['LedgerCode'] = LedgerCode
```

Hopefully, the above code could solve your problem.

Comment: That was what I first tried, but you then need to rearrange the columns to match the desired output.  Hence inserting it ends up being simpler.

Comment: @Alexander Yeah, using _insert_ does make it simpler, but just for exploring, the following code also works for this case.
 `cols = df.columns
  df['LedgerCode'] = LedgerCode
  df = df[['LedgerCode'] + list(cols)] 
 `

Answer (score 1):

Just insert a new ledger column in the dataframe (inplace):

```
df.insert(loc=0, column='ledger_code', value='02')
```